# Como fazer o Filter após apertar alguma tecla do teclado, o ENTER por exemplo

Tags: angularjs

Existe alguma forma de fazer o filtro do registro a partir do enter, não em tempo de execução como é de costume do Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode implementar uma diretiva:

```
angular.module('meuApp').directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Você pode então utilizar o adereço `ng-enter` em um controle:

```
<input type="text" name="Procura" placeholder="Procura" ng-model="Termos" ng-enter="Procura()">
```

Comment: agradeço muito, me ajudou bastante. obrigado mesmo